# Argument conversion for function taking an arg as 'const arg *&'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

Here is a problem  i am facing while reviving a old code

here is another one--

so here is definition of a function:-

```
int shen_get_entity_from_list(const ENTITY_LIST& list, const ENTITY*& e);
```

and here is the way that variables are defined

```
ENTITY *t_ent = NULL, *p_e = NULL, *s_e = NULL, *t_e = NULL;
```

now when i call this function

```
s_pos = shen_get_entity_from_list(sortedACISfeatureList, s_e);
```

it gives me the following error

> error C2664: `'shen_get_entity_from_list'` : cannot convert parameter 2 from `'ENTITY *'` to `'const ENTITY *&'`

Comment: Just out of interest: Is there a reason to pass a *const* reference to a pointer?? I don't get it

Comment: @Niklas : It's not a const reference to a pointer, it's a reference to a pointer to a const object. In the scenario that the function may modify the pointer but not the pointed-to-object, this is simple const-correctness (i.e. A Good Thing).

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks for the great explanation :) These type declarations always get me.

Answer (score 1):

The s_e variable needs to be declared as:

```
const ENTITY* s_e = NULL;
```

to match the declaration of the function.  This says that you won't use the s_e pointer to modify the ENTITY that it points so after the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

isn't the reference already const type? and requires value at creation time itself?

null pointer references aren't allowed.

because of all these i don't feel this problem is solvable

Answer (score -1):

Try moving the const:

```
int shen_get_entity_from_list(const ENTITY_LIST& list, ENTITY* const& e);
```

This gives you a const-reference to the type you are passing, rather than a non-const reference to a pointer to a const ENTITY.

Comment: Hm, but why should it fail to convert the argument in the first place?

Comment: @NiklasB. because if `shen_get_entity_from_list` changed `e` to point to a const ENTITY object, then after it returned the ENTITY* you passed in (`s_e`) would be a non-const pointer to a const object, violating the rules of const.